# Updating reactive just once

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a reactive plot I'm drawing that I would like to update just once after it's called.

I tried using invalidateLater, but this runs indefinitely, and I can't seem to figure out the logic to make it only run one time. I tried doing stuff like creating a true/false variable but it seems like it resets whenever invalidatelater runs

e: ok, some code. For example,

```
output$uiGooglePlot <- reactive({
  invalidateLater(1000, session)
```

This works, but runs over and over which screws a few things up in the plot. I would like to run it or something equivalent once

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I'm pretty sure people will react poorly if you don't at least give some code or some kind of attempt (i.e. code with `invalidateLater` in it). It also makes it a lot easier to understand the context of this all. Just a heads up :)

Comment: Try use `isolate` http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html

Comment: added some code. For isolate, how exactly would I do that? I was looking into isolate but I couldnt figure it out

Comment: First, to clarify, when you say you want it to update once, do you mean it will be drawn twice? (once initially and then update once), or just once?

Comment: I would like it to be drawn twice, so the invalidateLater is ran just once. The thing I'm having trouble with is getting the logic of an if-else statement or something that would work since the variables I create, even in global, seem to reset when invalidateLater happens

Comment: what makes it update after it has been drawn initially?

Comment: Just have another variable determine, when the plot should be redrawn. The other variable can be modified (or not) based on some invalidateLater command.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more? The problem I'm having is when I do invalidateLater any variables I create get reset, so I can't have something first set to true then set to false for example